# PHP MySQL if equals else INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I Have the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// connect to your MySQL database here 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
$selected = mysql_select_db("xxxx",$dbhandle);

// Get the winner data
function setWinner(){
    $sql = 'UPDATE user SET winner = 1 WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM user ORDER BY RAND())';
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $query;
}
// Get the winner data
function getWinner()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id, fullname, email, number FROM user WHERE winner = 1';
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    } else {
        // If there is no winner yet, automatically create one
        setWinner();

        // Recall the function which should now find a winner
        $user = getWinner();        
    }


    return $user;
}
$winner = getWinner();
print_r($winner);
?>
```

Trying to work with g4vroche's answer but getting this error: **You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause**

I used this for a competition to select a random user from the database, but i now need it  to look through all the users to see if there's a user that's winner column equals 1 and if there isn't one it should select the random user and update that users winner column with 1.

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use two queries?  That would work just fine, and you wouldn't need to use some complex nested query.

Comment: because i am stupid :), i did try the two queries route i probably did something wrong.. could you show some example code?

Comment: You really should stop using mysql_* and start using mysqli_* or PDO as mysql_* is now deprecated. Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven show what you have and maybe we can fix it.

Comment: you know what.. i am using mysqli.. i guess i am just use to saying mysql sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your winner column actually stores, but assuming it's a boolean, which may contains only 0 or 1, you could do this in a single query :

```
SELECT id, fullname, email, number FROM user ORDER BY winner DESC, RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Which will :

- Sort all records on winner column, making rows hanving winner = 1 firsts
- Sort equals records with RAND()

So you will get and random result, priority being given to records having winner column equals to "1".

## EDIT

I missunderstood your need.

You have two different process here

- Get the winner
- Set the winner

You should probably split that into two function / methods

```
// Get the winner data
function getWinner()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id, fullname, email, number FROM user winner=1';
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $user = mysql_fetc_assoc($query);           
        return $user;
    }

    return false;
}

function setWinner()
{
    $sql = 'UPDATE user SET winner=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
    mysql_query($sql);
}

// Call this one time
setWiner();

// Call this any time you want to get the winner's data
$winner = getWinner();
```

A more lazy approach, will be to make the getWinner() function to call setwinner if there is no winner yet :

```
// Get the winner data
function getWinner()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id, fullname, email, number FROM user winner=1';
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $user = mysql_fetc_assoc($query);

    } else {
        // If there is no winner yet, automatically create one
        setWinner();

        // Recall the function which should now find a winner
        $user = getWinner();        
    }


    return $user;
}
```

That's up to your context, but on general point of view it's bad practice, because a function which looks like reading data (getSomething) will, under some circumstances, also alter data (call to setWinner().

Comment: but all the winners are 0 from the start then when i need to pick a random user i also need to update his winner column to 1

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your need. That is totally two differents operations. I'll edit my answer

Comment: You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You are right, Mysql doesn't handle this. I edited the example code with a working (tested) query to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the `mysql_query()` function just because you used it in your example.  You should read up on [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and implement that instead.

Per my comment above,

```
require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
// look for records with `winner` set to 1
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id, fullname, email, number FROM user WHERE winner = 1 LIMIT 1') or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) { // if no records were found, pick a random row
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT id, fullname, email, number FROM user ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
}
```

Comment: Would I then set winner = 1 if not found in the second query or?

Comment: You'd set `winner = 1` for whichever record the second query found (since it'd already be set if returned by the first query).  The problem here is that you'd have to `UPDATE user SET winner = 0` and reset everyone's "winner" status at some point so the same user doesn't get returned over and over again.